# Can the Stack Overflow Talents logo be updated to look nice in dark mode?

Tags: bug, status-completed, dark-mode, logo, stack-overflow-talent

On [the Stack Overflow Talent page](https://stackoverflow.co/talent/) in dark mode (toggle is in the footer), here's what the dark-mode logo looks like. I find the pretty much black text tough to read on the dark-grey background.

[image]

But wait, let's scroll down a bit. Here's what it looks like when one scrolls down:

[image]

I find that *even harder* to read. Of course, I'm fully aware I'm on the SO Talent website, but I feel the logo should look good in dark mode too.

For comparison, here's what it looks like on [stackoverflow.co](https://stackoverflow.co/)

[image]

And when scrolled:

[image]

Given that it looks fine on the main stackoverflow.co site, I'd assume this is simply an oversight, but I still think it would be great if SO Talents used the light colored text for "stack**overflow**" in dark mode.